# BootstrapUI Timepicker Meridian depend on Browser Settings

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, internationalization, angular-ui-bootstrap

How can I make BootstrapUI for AngularJS only display the meridian for user's that do not use the 24h format? Germans for example use 24h and are not used to meridians. The website is international.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check out PLUNKER link at https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/timepicker,
in html file this line will show meridians:

```
<div uib-timepicker ng-model="mytime" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="true"></div>
```

and this one - not:

```
<div uib-timepicker ng-model="mytime" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="false"></div>
```

just set *show-meridian* attribute to *false*

Comment: Thank you, but this is rather obvious. I was wondering more if the timepicker can automatically decide if it should display it or not - based on the location and settings of the current user.